# Can I assume that OpenMP shared variables are read and written atomically?

Tags: c, openmp, shared-memory

For instance, assume I have a variable that cannot be accessed by the underlying processor in one instruction (e.g. 64 bit integer on a 32 bit architecture).

```
// let x, y, z of the same integral type of size > architecture
#pragma omp parallel shared(x), private(y,z)
  y = ...;
  z = ...;
  if (x == y)
    x = z;
```

While there could be races between the `if` statement and the actual assignment, could half of `x` be read before a context switch, and the other half afterwards? Or is it guaranteed that read and write access to shared variables always happens atomically? I cannot find any statements regarding this in the standard.

Comment: No, that's a bad idea...

Comment: @Mysticial: so, if it's a bad idea, this would imply that the standard does not guarantee atomicity here?

Comment: That's correct. So you'll have to manually protect them.

Answer (score 0):

No and no. This code will result in resource race.

Comment: How can both questions be answered with a "no"? I thought they were mutually exclusive. Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: That was enhancement of the meaning )))  I think such operations are not atomic, as I remember  from assembly studying ))